# Print all tabs of a page using jquery PrintArea

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have an issue and i was wondering if anyone can help me, imagine i have an htlm page on the head section i m using the

```
  <script src="../js/jquery.PrintArea.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then i m using tabs and a function for my print button like

```
  <script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function () {         
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();        
    $("#print_button").click(function(){
    $("div.PrintArea").printArea( );
   });
```

.......
and then in the body i m showing the tabs and the print button like that,

```
  <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">TAB1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">TAB2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">TAB3</a></li>         
      </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"></div>
 </div>
 <button type="submit" id="print_button" ><img src="../images/printer.png" alt="print icon"  style="vertical-align:text-bottom;"/> PRINT PAGE </button>
```

Question1: like that i m printing the active tab,,, but, i want to print all tabs at once! on a single click
Question2: how can i resize the printing size to fit on a page ?

i can do that with css ? but now i want just to use the jquery.PrintArea.js .. :(

Please some help i m sure its an easy task but i m stack now...any help would be really apreciated..
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok guys, i found a solution for my problem and is working like a charm here it is in case anyone else need it,

1st solution

1. create a print.css in your project root and add it in your page like that

   ```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print"/>
   ```
2. on that css add the folowing lines

   ```
   .ui-tabs-nav { display: none; }
   .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide { display: block !important; }
   .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel { display: block !important; }
   ```

and job is done..

2nd solution

just add the following script to handle your print button ,,but not global solution i prefer the 1st one

```
  $("#printButton").click(function(){
  // Before printing show all the tab panel contents
  $('.ui-tabs-panel').show();
  // Print the page
  window.print();
  // After printing hide back all the tab panel contents which are supposed to be hidden
  $('.ui-tabs-panel[aria-hidden=true]').hide();
  });
```

thank you guys

Answer (score 2):

Great solution. I improved upon this by *extending* the tabs widget. Not only does it allow printing of all tabs, but also puts the appropriate header, which it automatically gets from the tabs definition. The print-header style can be customized by the `print-tab-hdr` CSS class. You can put the widget into a separate script, as well as the screen and print css into separate files as shown by dc03kks. Then all you need in the main file is to modify the tabs hookup as: **`$( "#tabs" ).tabs().tabs("tabsPrint");`**.

Here is the full code in a single file:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body{font:9pt arial}
  @media print{
  .ui-tabs-nav { display: none; }
  .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide { display: block !important; }
  .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel { display: block !important; }
  .print-tab-hdr{font:bold 1.2em arial;color:maroon}
  }
  @media screen {
  .print-tab-hdr{display:none}
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $.widget( "ui.tabs", $.ui.tabs, { //extend tabs widget to allow printing all tabs WITH TAB HEADERS
      tabsPrint: function() {
        var tabdivs = this.element.find("a");
        for(i=0;i<tabdivs.length;i++){
            var hdrMarkup = "<div class=print-tab-hdr>" + tabdivs[i].text +  "</div>";
            var targetDiv = $(tabdivs[i].getAttribute("href"));
            targetDiv.prepend(hdrMarkup);
        }
      }
    });
    //now hookup tabs with the print functionality
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().tabs("tabsPrint");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Vijay Jagdale for your good words, really appreciated.. :),, great expanding of your solution as well..